# How to setup server side render with Cloudfare Workers

Tags: server-side-rendering, cloudflare-workers

How can i set up server side rendered pages with Cloudflare Workers ? What frameworks support CF Workers in that sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: you can use Nuxt3 with the `cloudflare` Nitro preset.

Here i will higligth a simple course of action thinking even in folks that never used Nuxt before.

1. Check out the Nuxt3 [getting started](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/introduction/)
2. [Create a project](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/installation)
3. Learn [how](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/cloudflare) to setup Nitro (the underliyng engine) to export a serverside renderer cloudfare worker
4. Deploy using Wrangler cli as described in the above article
5. Optionally but higly recomended (to even watch this first) see this short but enligthing talk about [how all of this works](https://www.youtube.com/embed/K1nMTSRH8Ug)